# CakeDC User Plugin - Is there Documentation Anywhere?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, authentication, cakedc

Browsing through [GitHub](https://github.com/CakeDC/users) and I found a pretty powerful [CakePHP plugin called **CakeDC Users**](https://github.com/CakeDC/users) that has a lot of features (Account verification, password reset, etc) for a creating a login/authentication system. I like it because it seems to be written by some of the actual CakePHP developers and it gets updated a lot but there seems to be absolutely **zero** documentation anywhere on it. I've just come across this plugin recently, since I was trying to see if there's a better way than "rolling" with my own solution. So I was wondering if anybody here has had experience with it and if so could point to some decent documentation online.

**Edit** There is some stuff at the bottom of the readme, but it hasn't been too intuitive for me.

Alternate question, if you don't use this plugin, is there a login/authentication plugin you use in CakePHP that you use for login/authentication?

Comment: Were you able to successfully use this plugin? I am in the same boat....can't find any documentation on how to precisely include this plugin... ran through cake console but nothing works...any tips?

Comment: Claiming that there is "zero" documentation is just a proof you did not even spent one minute reading the readme.md...

Comment: @burzum My question was submitted 2 years ago bud...you don't think things might have changed since then? Regardless, I haven't used this plugin in the past year anyways. Stop trying to be tough.

Answer (score 4):

I have ran into the same problem with using the CakeDC plugins, a lot of them have little/no documentation.

However, there is not "Zero" documentation for it, you can see how to set it up for the most part at the bottom of the [github page in the read me](https://github.com/CakeDC/users#readme). Also you need to put this inside your AppController::beforeFilter() method.

```
$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd');
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
$this->Auth->authError = __('Sorry, but you need to login to access this location.', true);
$this->Auth->loginError = __('Invalid e-mail / password
combination.  Please try again', true);
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = true;
$this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
if ($this->Auth->user()) {
    $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
    $this->set('isAuthorized', ($this->Auth->user('id') != ''));
}
```

Also, you need an `isAuthorized()` function, something as simple as this will do:

```
public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}
```

Additionally, you will need to allow the 'login' action (this will involve editing the plugin files). Just add 'login' to the `$this->Auth->allow()` in `users_controller.php`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I saw the readme, but I wasn't completely clear on what to do there.  I understand what its meant to do ( extend the plugin), but I'm unsure on how to go about it

Comment: You don't need to extend the plugin, just drop it in and you're away

Comment: It works nice only if I use $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller'); instead of $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';

Answer (score 1):

After exhaustive search I found a tutorial on how to use CakeDC!

**[Here it is](http://zaidisoft.com/cakedc-users-plugin-install-guide-cakephp-application/)**

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: @Sam thanks - looks like the blog owner changed the path! Fixed the link :-)

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old now, but as it's not marked as resolved and we've been doing a lot on the documentation since then I think it's worth to update:

Documentation can be found here:

#### For the version 3+ of the framework

- https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Home.md
- Tutorial > http://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2016/02/21/cakedc_users_plugin_for_cakephp_3_-_update
- CakePHP Facebook login tutorial > 
  http://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2016/02/21/cakephp_facebook_login_using_cakedc_users_plugin_-_update_3_1_5

#### For the (old) version 2

- https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.x/Docs/Home.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.