# CakePHP-2.0, cakedc users plugin: It's not login successfully and it's not redirecting

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

https://github.com/cakedc/users

I have registered an account successfully with cakedc users plugin and got email to confirm email i click that link from email to confirm email. That is done.

Whatever i type from the http://site/users/login and click the submit button it redirects the same http://site/users/login page.

I have typed the email and the password. If i type wrong password or email, it doesn't give me any message saying that wrong username or password.

routes.php =>

```
Router::connect('/', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

Router::connect('/users/:action',array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
```

Why can't i login? After login which page it is supposed to redirect to? Did i miss something to configure ? Or is it comparing a plain password with hashed password of users table ?

If you need additional information please mention.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461705/cakedc-user-plugin-is-there-documentation-anywhere

Comment: Do i have to add isAuthorised function in AppController ?

Comment: Additionally, you will need to allow the 'login' action (this will involve editing the plugin files). Just add 'login' to the $this->Auth->allow() in users_controller.php. , there is no users_controller.php

Comment: It's UsersController.php in Cake 2.0, You should have been able to work that out!

Comment: $this->Auth->allow('login'); should i add this in app/Plugin/Users/Controlers/UsersController.php ?

Comment: Yes, there will already be a long line with `$this->Auth->allow()` on it.

Comment: It's cakephp-2 , not 1.3, so the link you gave is for cakephp-1.3 users plugin , check this again.